# For loop should iterate twice with one value in apex code

Tags: apex, loop

here is my code.

```
        accountList[1].ParentId = accountList[0].Id;
        accountsToUpdate.add(accountList[1]);
        
        accountList[2].ParentId = accountList[0].Id;
        accountsToUpdate.add(accountList[2]);

        accountList[3].ParentId = accountList[1].Id;
        accountsToUpdate.add(accountList[3]);
        
        accountList[4].ParentId = accountList[1].Id;
        accountsToUpdate.add(accountList[4]);
        
        accountList[5].ParentId = accountList[2].Id;
        accountsToUpdate.add(accountList[5]);
        
        accountList[6].ParentId = accountList[2].Id;
        accountsToUpdate.add(accountList[6]);
```

can you suggest how to optimize this code by using for loop like this way(it may be wrong,correct me).

```
for(i=1;i<=14;i++)
            {
                accountList[i].ParentId = accountList[**how use the varaiable here can anyone help 
                                                me out with the solution**].Id;
                accountsToUpdate.add(accountList[i]);
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to solve this; here's one.

```
Integer i = 1;
for (j = 0; j < 14/2; j++) {
  accountsToUpdate.addAll(new List<Account> {
     accountList[i].ParentId = accountList[j].Id,
     accountList[i+1].ParentId = accountList[j].Id
  });
  i = i + 2;
}
```